# Apply style, only if both classes are in use (media queries / bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

Even if my browser is resized to use the `sm` style, this text-align applies to it - despite telling it to apply on `md-3`, not `sm`

In other words, I want to be able to apply a style only if media queries interprets my device as an `sm` screen. The style I have below, applies to all sizes - even `md`. How do I fix it?

My CSS:

```
div.col-md-3.subnav{
    text-align: center;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 subnav">Pricing</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's applied because there is class `subnav` on the div which defines `text-align: center` irrespective of current dimension.

You need to add media query rule for your specific alignment:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .subnav {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```